# Apple Watchkit Activity Indicator

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, apple-watch

Actually i am calling a web service in apple watch extension but i am not able to show activity indicator.Could you please let me know how to show activity indicator in watch kit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an ActivityIndicator in WatchKit for Apple Watch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905131/is-there-an-activityindicator-in-watchkit-for-apple-watch)

Answer (score 4):

`UIActivityIndicator` doesn't exist in WatchKit. You'll need to roll your own solution.