# Apple Watch cannot find Activity Indicator

Tags: ios, watchkit, uiactivityindicatorview

I am developing an Apple Watch application in which I am calling an API which takes some time to execute, so to show user process is going on I need to show Activity Indicator. I am trying hard to find the solution as there is no Activity Indicator included in Apple Watch. One solution is to take image and animate image when we start the process and hide when we get response but is there any better solution as we need to add multiple images?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no activity indicator interface element in WatchKit. You can create your own using the technique you've described. That is, unhide and begin an animated image sequence while you're waiting for a response, and hide it when the operation is complete.

This is the exact same technique that I use in my own Watch app. In my case, I load 4 images, so there are 4 unique activity indicator images that "spin" while the images are retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom Activity Indicator using `WKInterfaceImage` like this;

```
IBOutlet WKInterfaceImage *animatedImage;
```

Now add images in sequence for animation in `WKInterfaceImage` in `Images.xcassets`

### [image]

The method for hiding and unhiding activity indicator :

```
-(void)showActivityIndicator:(BOOL)yesOrNo
{
  if (yesOrNo) 
  {
    //unhide
    [self.animatedImage setHidden:NO];

    // Uses images in WatchKit app bundle.
    [self.animatedImage setImageNamed:@"ActInd"];
    [self.animatedImage startAnimating];
  }
  else
  {
    [self.animatedImage stopAnimating];

    //hide
    [self.animatedImage setHidden:YES];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use WKInterfaceImage set Images  spinner@2x1.png and then animate image using  startAnimatingWithImagesInRange

Now add images in sequence for animation in WKInterfaceImage in Images.x cassets 
 spinner@2x1.png,spinner@2x2.png.....spinner@2x40.png

Then use following method

```
NSRange model = NSMakeRange(0, 40);

 /*  set Image to ImageView */

    [self.spinnerImage setImageNamed:@"spinner@2x1.png"]; 
    /*  set repeat count 0 for continues rotation */ 
    [self.spinnerImage startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:model
                                                        duration:1.0
                                                     repeatCount:0];
```

This method works but it not smooth and if need set in center  of view, then image needs to hidden first then unhide and animate image while process is going on  and again hide after we get response,and if their multiple view then it becomes hectic is there any way to add image above all views or create dynamic activity indicator so that we add any where we need

Answer (score 0):

'WatchKit`has no UI control like`ActivityIndicator`, but we can create custom activityIndicator with the help of`WKInterfaceImage`.
You can find more more detail on this [stackoverflow-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905131/is-there-an-activityindicator-in-watchkit-for-apple-watch?lq=1).