# Can I display a network activity indicator in the apple watch status bar?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, watchos

On iOS, you can use `UIApplication.networkActivityIndicatorVisible` to display an activity indicator in the status bar. I've seen Apple's weather app on the watch do the same thing.

Is there a public API to do this in watchOS 2? There doesn't appear to be an equivalent `WKExtension.networkActivityIndicatorVisible` property.

**Update:** I'm aware it's possible to [roll my own using animated images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905131), but I'm specifically talking about the network activity indicator in the status bar, as seen in Apple's Weather app. (The accepted answer on that question suggests that watch apps should not be doing networking. This hasn't been true since native watch apps and the introduction of the WatchConnectivity framework with watchOS 2.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an ActivityIndicator in WatchKit for Apple Watch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905131/is-there-an-activityindicator-in-watchkit-for-apple-watch)

Comment: Currently it is not possible without creating custom constructs, not really comfortable to use.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no option to access the network indicator on Apple Watch as there is not any.

WatchOS does not have any status bar indicators at all (status indicators on apple watch: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205550).

If you are trying to create activity indicator you can use static images and animate them (like this library: https://github.com/hirokimu/EMTLoadingIndicator)

Comment: As of December 2020, [Apple's website](https://support.apple.com/guide/watch/status-icons-apdce21b02a0/watchos) shows a status icon for `There’s wireless activity or an active process happening` which looks a lot like the [Network Activity Indicator on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/progress-indicators/).