# Apple Watch "No such module 'Alamofire'"

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, alamofire

Alamofire has been working fine for an iPhone only project.

I DID THE MANUAL INSTALL OF ALAMOFIRE - NOT COCOA PODS

Now I have added a watch app target following these steps - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringYourXcodeProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH2-SW1IIm

"import Alamofire" works fine on the iPhone's view controller but when I try to add it to one of the code files in the " Extension" Folder the following error occurs...

```
No such module "Alamofire"
```

[image: My Directory]

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't use http requests from WatchKit extension at all. Take a look at a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28931587/1689376

Comment: How would I link parsed JSON data in the view controller for the iOS app onto the watch?

Comment: How would I put a variable from the iPhone onto the Watches UI???

Comment: I don't think my project would function with that method...

Comment: Could I do it without Alamofire???

Answer (score 1):

**Below 2 steps  have resolved above issue  :**

> i) Check the target name in the Podfile it should match with extension
>   that you are adding Library to it. "AppleWatchApp Extension" instead
>   of "AppleWatchApp" in my case .
>
> ii) Change the **framework search Path** in **BUILD SETTINGS** in the target
>   as mention below.

[image]